# Change mail for sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online

after a request of one of our users, we managed to change the name of a sharepointsite, but now they also want to change the name of the mail address. I haven't found this yet. Is this possible and if so, how do I proceed?

Jo

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to change the name, you will need to create a new one with your preferred name to set it to your group!

Once you created the new email with your preferred name, you can now use `Set-UnifiedGroup` to update the current assigned email with the new one as the following:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Group Name" -EmailAddresses: @{Add ="New Email"}
```

**Finally,** remove the old email like the following:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup -Identity "Group Name" -EmailAddresses: @{Remove="old email"}
```

> **Note:** The below address can't be changed
>
> - mailbox email address.
> - group email address
> - no-reply@sharepointonline address

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is the Email address for the connected Office 365 Group. You can update this using PowerShell:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/users-and-groups/set-unifiedgroup?view=exchange-ps

Example:

```
Set-UnifiedGroup –Identity ExistingName –PrimarySmtpAddress newemail@yourdomain.com
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the email address of a Group site, you can have a try with **Set-UnifiedGroup** cmdlet, refer to the article:
[Is there a way to change O365 group email address using powershell](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/office-365-groups/is-there-a-way-to-change-o365-group-email-address-using/m-p/49872)

And also this one:
[Change Office 365 Group or Team Email Address](https://www.tecklyfe.com/change-office-365-group-or-team-email-address/)